# Android - Loading Dialog not appearing when an activity is launched, but only from certain activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am working on an app that uses the same activity for all webViews since the only thing that needs to change is the url that it is loading. I have a loading dialog popup because otherwise it just white pages for a bit. The problem is, that loading dialog works for every instance except for when I start the webpage activity from the main activity. This is the launching code from the main activity. Different buttons change the intent.

**Edit**: By does not work, I mean that it loads the webpage, but no dialog pops up, and it just sits at a white screen as if I had not shouldOverrideUrlLoading at all. It doesn't even print debugs that I've put in there. It's using my new webClient for sure because it does not have any of the features of the default one. So basically, shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not being called (but onPageFinished is)

**Edit 2**: I forgot, logcat is also outputting nativeDestroy View from tag webViewGlue

```
    Intent i = null;
    // check which button was pressed, and then create the new intent
    if (v == btnParticipants) {
        i = new Intent(this, DetailedList.class);
        i.putExtra("choice", Constants.SPONSOR_PAGE);
    } else if (v == btnDirectionMap) {
        i = new Intent(this, DirectionMapActivity.class);
    } else if (v == btnEventMap) {
        i = new Intent(this, EventMapActivity.class);
    } else if (v == btnSchedule) {
        i = new Intent(this, DetailedList.class);
        i.putExtra("choice", Constants.ATTRACTION_PAGE);
    } else if (v == btnSavedSchedule) {
        i = new Intent(this, DetailedList.class);
        i.putExtra("choice", Constants.MY_ATTRACTIONS);
    } else if (v == btnRegistration) {
        i = new Intent(this, Webpage.class);
        i.putExtra("url", RetrievalEngine.getInstance().mainEvent.eventWebsite);
    } else if (v == btnQR) {

    } else if (v == btnFacebook) {

    } else if (v == btnTwitter) {
        i = new Intent(this, TwitterActivity.class);
    } else if (v == btnWebsite) {

    } else if (v == btnAbout) {
        i = new Intent(this, AboutScreen.class);
    }

    // if a new intent was created, start it
    if (i != null) {
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

That code does not work but this one does and it is from an about page where v is a view(button in this case):

```
    if (v == btnWebsite){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Webpage.class);
        i.putExtra("url", url);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Both are doing the exact same thing so I can't figure out why it isn't working.

Also, here is the Webpage activity:

```
WebView webView;
static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    this.finish();
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

public void onFinish(){
    webView.destroy();
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web);
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    Button backBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    final TextView lbl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.webPageDesc);
    lbl.setText("Loading...");
    backBtn.setText("Back");
    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View viewArg) {
            WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            if (view.canGoBack()) {
                view.goBack();
            }
        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            lbl.setText("Loading...");

            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
            try{
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }catch(Exception e){}
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading " + url);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            if(view.getTitle().length() > 33){
                lbl.setText(view.getTitle().substring(0, 30) + "...");
            }else{
                lbl.setText(view.getTitle());
            }
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String url = extras.getString("url");
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Does it crash? If so, please post the logcat

Comment: 'if/else' mess - haven't you heard of `switch/case`?

Comment: 1. That's not helpful to my question at all.
2. Yes I have.
3. I didn't write this code, I just got put on the project.

Comment: 4. Switches would look just as bad, worse in fact because of the break statements. So please get off your high horse and stop posting stupid beginner answers that are not helpful to anyone or pertain to the question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the code from shouldOverrideUrlLoading to onPageStarted, and it's working.